# Additional Capabilities not showing in Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

I made a simple flashlight app with the following XML code in manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

The permission screen is perfect in Android Marshmallow. The "All Permissions" screen displays Camera permission and flashlight under additional Capabilities But Android 7.0(Motorola Moto G 5 plus) does not list flashlight in my app's additional Capabilities and my app also does not work on it. I can't provide the logcat as of now but will provide it soon in an edit. Does anyone else know of any permission changes? Please help me make it compatible with Android 7.0.

**Edit:** Here is the logcat:

> 06-28 15:40:00.136 19036-19036/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   06-28 15:40:00.165 19036-19036/com.camera2 W/System: ClassLoader
>   referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.camera2-1/lib/arm 06-28
>   15:40:00.207 19036-19036/com.camera2 I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting
>   to camera service 06-28 15:40:00.233 19036-19036/com.camera2
>   I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL. 06-28 15:40:00.313
>   19036-19036/com.camera2 I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
>   06-28 15:40:00.316 19036-19057/com.camera2 E/Camera: Error 2 06-28
>   15:40:00.316 19036-19057/com.camera2 I/RequestThread-0: Flushing all
>   pending requests. 06-28 15:40:00.316 19036-19057/com.camera2
>   E/RequestQueue: cancel failed: no repeating request exists. 06-28
>   15:40:00.317 19036-19057/com.camera2 I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy
>   camera service transitioning to state ERROR 06-28 15:40:00.583
>   19036-19036/com.camera2 I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service
>   transitioning to state CONFIGURING 06-28 15:40:00.583
>   19036-19036/com.camera2 E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot call configure
>   while in state: 0 06-28 15:40:00.593 19036-19036/com.camera2
>   I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state
>   CONFIGURING 06-28 15:40:00.593 19036-19168/com.camera2
>   I/RequestThread-0: Configure outputs: 1 surfaces configured. 06-28
>   15:40:00.593 19036-19168/com.camera2 D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
>   06-28 15:40:00.600 19036-19170/com.camera2 I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build
>   : bc479b6, I15255e4b4a
>                                                        Build Date                       : 02/22/17
>                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
>                                                        Local Branch                     : 
>                                                        Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.5.R1.07.00.00.269.019
>                                                        Remote Branch                    : NONE
>                                                        Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING 06-28 15:40:00.617
>   19036-19036/com.camera2 I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service
>   transitioning to state IDLE 06-28 15:40:00.632 19036-19169/com.camera2
>   I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 06-28 15:40:00.632
>   19036-19169/com.camera2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 06-28
>   15:40:00.639 19036-19036/com.camera2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM 06-28 15:40:00.639 19036-19036/com.camera2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                Process: com.camera2, PID: 19036
>                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session has been closed; further
>   changes are illegal.
>                                                                    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.checkNotClosed(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:606)
>                                                                    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:227)
>                                                                    at com.camera2.MainActivity$a.onConfigured(Unknown Source)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                    at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
>                                                                    at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Comment: Do you have runtime permission from the user?

Comment: I don't currently check for the permission but I have explicitly granted my app permission from the settings window and it still doesn't work.

Comment: debug your code may be the permission is not getting.

Comment: But it works on Android Marshmallow which also requires runtime permission .

Comment: Hard to say anything without the exact error message from logcat.

Comment: I don't currently have that device will have to wait for sometime 

Comment: @Henry Posted the logcat. Please help

Comment: Does not look like a permission issue. Could be either a bug in the camera app or in the way you enable the flash light. Maybe you are ignoring an exception? We need to see the respective code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling around in my code, I found out that it was as easy as adding an IllegalStateException catcher. As for the additional capabilities, it does not hinder my app's functionality so it does not matter.